# How to plot a boxplot for each column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame `df` of multiple columns and I would like to create a `boxplot` **for each column** using `matplotlib`.

`df.info()` output of my DataFrame below for reference

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9568 entries, 0 to 9567
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Ambient Tempreature    9568 non-null float64
Exhaust Vacuum         9568 non-null float64
Ambient Pressure       9568 non-null float64
Relative Humidity      9568 non-null float64
PE                     9568 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 373.8 KB
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to create a separate plot per column, then you can iterate over each column and use `plt.figure()` to initiate a new figure for each plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for column in df:
    plt.figure()
    df.boxplot([column])
```

If you want to just put all columns into the same boxplot graph then you can just use `df.plot(kind='box')`

Comment: This produces an error `KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any spaces in your column names? Can you change them to `-` or `_` and try again? if not sufficient to resolve your issue, please post your `df` and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" by excluding the object dtype variables from your dataframe

```
df1=df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
```

and then run

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for column in df1:
        plt.figure(figsize=(17,1))
        sns.boxplot(data=df1, x=column)
```